# Snow Leopard - Add application to System tray instead of the dock

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dock

I have lots of apps in the dock right now and I wish to move some of them to the top system tray where options like Bluetooth, Spotlight, Sound, and Airport (Wifi) are displayed. How can I do this in Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6)?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this should be in superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

The "system tray" is officially called the menu bar in Mac OS X - some applications create a menu item (eg. Twitter clients, iStat menus, Dropbox) that can be placed there but a normal application can not be added to the menu bar as it would be from the dock.

To make applications available in the menu bar you can try some of the application launchers that are designed for the menu bar such as [ALaunch](http://mactips-lib.net/m/software/alaunch/en/main.html) or [HimmelBar](http://softbend.free.fr/himmelbar/).

Are you finding you have too many applications in the Dock and that is why you want to use the menu bar?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using quicksilver or spotlight for finding application easily and quickly

Comment: Or Google Quick Search Box. Take a look at the launchers at iusethis, http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/launcher

Comment: +1 - I would definitely also suggest Quicksilver as a cure for an overcrowded Dock.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The "status bar" (what you and Windows call the system tray) has a special API that applications can use to put items there, but users can't just put Dock icons into it :(.

Answer (score 0):

I use something called "[overflow](http://stuntsoftware.com/overflow/)" that expand the capacity of the dock.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to create a folder where you put application aliases. then you can drag this folder to the dock. That way, you have created a dock stack with your too many applications.